# How to play online video using ExoPlayer which is encrypted?

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to play encrypted videos using ExoPlayer I am very new to ExoPlayer I don't know much about that. I found some links[https://stackoverflow.com/a/54247524/9789670] but those are not working fine.I need some help regrading this issue

Comment: hey, did you find the solutions? if not do you want to play youtube video type encryption?

Comment: @KamranAli noo I did not find the solution I want exoplayer to behave like that only

Comment: **If you want the solution for youTube I can give you that.**

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code for play video
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(null);
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
            SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContxt, trackSelector);

            DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(mContxt, 
 Util.getUserAgent(mContxt, "CloudExoplayer"));
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
            MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(videoUri);
            player.prepare(videoSource);
            player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
            exoplayer.setPlayer(player);
            exoplayer.requestFocus();
            exoplayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: this code is useful to play normal video but I want to play the encrypted video